# Adobe Flex 3 : Fault Event doesnt return XML Feed sent from Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache-flex, flex3

I am working on a flex application which communicates with a Rails backened.
When i request for some data, It sends back xml feed.

In some cases, if given parameters are not valid, then rails return an error feed with status code = 422 as following
email is wrong

But I dont get this feed in FaultEvent of Flex, How could i read error feed?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting the result in ResultEvent in such cases? I am not sure for what all HTTP error codes FaultEvent will get invoke(I know only it goes for 404 and 500). May be its still going to ResultEvent as a valid result!

Comment: If it is going to result event, then  i would have gotten it already. But this only happens when RAILS generates an error feed with error code = 422.

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTTPService instead of URLLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Flex HTTP results will *not* include the actual underlying HTTP response codes. It just doesn't work. (TM)